# Как передать параметры макроса вовнутрь ассемблерной вставки для Tiny C Compiler?

Tags: c

Документации по встроенному ассемблеру Tiny C Compiler маловато. Документация, идущая в комплекте с компилятором, содержит единственный пример. И он совсем без комментариев. Хотелось бы понять, как написать макрос, передав его параметры во встроенный ассемблер, типа вот этого:

```
#define MY_COPY(TO, FROM) {__asm__ (" movl ?FROM?, %eax\n movl %eax, ?TO?");}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Такой макрос в общем случае не годится, ибо в определённых условиях он компилируется с ошибками:

```
#include  
int i,j;  // если эти переменные глобальны, то при компиляции ошибок нет
#define MY_COPY(TO,FROM) {__asm__ __volatile__("movl " #FROM ", %eax\nmovl %eax, " #TO);}
int  main() {
    //int i,j;      // Если переменные локальны, то ошибка при компиляции
    j=1000;
    MY_COPY(i,j);
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    //MY_COPY(i,999);   // Компиляция успешна, но ошибка run-time:
                        // в ассемблерной вставке должно быть $999
    MY_COPY(i,$999);
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    return  0;
};
```

А вот пример, взятый из документации к Tiny C Compiler:

```
#include  
static inline void * my_memcpy(void * to, const void * from, size_t n) {
    int d0, d1, d2;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "rep ; movsl\n\t"
        "testb $2,%b4\n\t"
        "je 1f\n\t"
        "movsw\n"
        "1:\ttestb $1,%b4\n\t"
        "je 2f\n\t"
        "movsb\n"
        "2:"
        : "=&c" (d0), "=&D" (d1), "=&S" (d2)
        :"0" (n/4), "q" (n),"1" ((long) to),"2" ((long) from)
        : "memory");
    return (to);
}
int  main() {
    char*  s1 = "It is my string";
    char  s2[20];
    my_memcpy (s2, s1, strlen(s1)+1);
    printf("look:\n%s",s2);
    return  0;
};
```

Но что значит вот это:

```
        : "=&c" (d0), "=&D" (d1), "=&S" (d2)
        :"0" (n/4), "q" (n),"1" ((long) to),"2" ((long) from)
        : "memory");
```

Думается, так передают параметры вовнутрь вставки. Но как понять это, где к этому есть документация?

Comment: В качестве "интерфейса" к ассемблерным вставкам, лучше использовать inline функции, а уже в них передавать параметры.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен насчёт вашего компилятора, но по идее должно получиться как-то так:

```
#define MY_COPY(TO, FROM) {__asm__("movl " #FROM ", %eax\nmovl %eax, " #TO); }
```

Или даже так:

```
#define MY_COPY(TO, FROM) do {__asm__("movl " #FROM ", %eax\nmovl %eax, " #TO); } while (0)
```

Пример: http://ideone.com/66vCoF